# 'arbor' layout doesn't work in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, arbor.js, cytoscape.js

I am attempting to get Cytoscape.js working on a web server, and it is working perfectly for the following layouts:
Random
Circle
Grid
But unfortunately, when I attempt to run the "arbor" (force-directed) model layout, my graph solely consists of a single node with no label, rather than the five node graph that I was expecting. I have run this with the exact options that cytoscape.js reccomends by default, and any options that aren't specified should be using the arbor.js defaults. I am unsure if it is perhaps my script src that is at fault, if so, what should I be importing? I have seen several other users with very similar problems using arbor with cytoscape.js, but none of those threads had been resolved in a helpful manner.

```
< style>
 #cy {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
< /style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/api/cytoscape.js-latest/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/master/build/extensions/cytoscape.layout.arbor.js"></script>

  <div style="height:700px;" name="cy" id="cy"></div>


< script>
  options = {
    name: 'arbor'
};

$('#cy').cytoscape({
  layout: options,
  style: cytoscape.stylesheet()
    .selector('node')
      .css({
        'content': 'data(name)',
    'shape': 'octagon',
    'width': '160',
    'height': '80',
        'text-valign': 'top',
        'text-halign': 'center',
    'font-size': '40',
        'color': 'black',
        'text-outline-width': 2,
        'text-outline-color': '#888'
      })
    .selector('edge')
      .css({
        'width': '5',
        'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
        'source-arrow-shape': 'circle'
      })
    .selector(':selected')
      .css({
        'background-color': 'black',
        'line-color': 'black',
        'target-arrow-color': 'black',
        'source-arrow-color': 'black'
      })
    .selector('.faded')
      .css({
        'opacity': 0.25,
        'text-opacity': 0
      }),

  elements: {
    nodes: [
      { data: { id: 'LOC_OS01G10320', name: 'LOC_OS01G10320' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS02G38090', name: 'LOC_OS02G38090' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS01G16030', name: 'LOC_OS01G16030' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS03G15550', name: 'LOC_OS03G15550' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS03G49800', name: 'LOC_OS03G49800' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS01G23630', name: 'LOC_OS01G23630' } },
{ data: { id: 'LOC_OS01G32750', name: 'LOC_OS01G32750' } }    ],
    edges: [
      { data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G10320', target: 'LOC_OS02G38090' } },
{ data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G16030', target: 'LOC_OS03G15550' } },
{ data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G16030', target: 'LOC_OS03G49800' } },
{ data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G16030', target: 'LOC_OS03G15550' } },
{ data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G16030', target: 'LOC_OS03G49800' } },
{ data: { source: 'LOC_OS01G23630', target: 'LOC_OS01G32750' } }    ]
  },

  ready: function(){
    document.cy = this;

    // giddy up...

    cy.elements().unselectify();

    cy.on('tap', 'node', function(e){
      var node = e.cyTarget; 
      var neighborhood = node.neighborhood().add(node);

      cy.elements().addClass('faded');
      neighborhood.removeClass('faded');
    });

    cy.on('tap', function(e){
      if( e.cyTarget === cy ){
        cy.elements().removeClass('faded');
      }
    });
  }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the docs:

### http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/visuals/cy.layout

NB: You must reference the version of arbor.js included with Cytoscape.js in the `<head>` of your HTML document:

```
<head>
    ...

    <script src="arbor.js"></script>

    ...
</head>
```

Arbor does some automatic path finding because it uses web workers, and so it must be included this way. Therefore, you can not combine arbor.js with your other JavaScript files — as you probably would as a part of the minification of the scripts in your webapp.

Comment: Thanks, that was possibly one problem that I was having. Eventually I solved this by correcting a few filepaths, and most importantly, importing jquery. When I was originally testing this, I went about it in such a way that by the time I remembered I needed to import jQuery, I had messed up my other filepath imports in an attempt to figure out what the problem was. All I needed was a little dose of the scientific method.